# Angularjs display given ISO formatted date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I'm looking for way to display/format date given in ISO format (with timezone).
From API i got encoded date: `"2015-04-17T06:00:00.000-05:00"` and i want to display it in human readable format.
When i use `{{"2015-04-17T06:00:00.000-05:00" date: 'hh:mm'}}` i got time converted to local timezone. I need only format it.

A searched Internet, but only found only huge libs like moments.js or others.
There did not found working answer here also...

If there is no angularjs solution i can use pure javascript, but not found that one either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the timezone yourself](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) with the date filter:

(It accepts format strings like `"+0000"` and simple integer strings like `"0"`)

```
{{"2015-04-17T06:00:00.000-05:00" | date:'hh:mm':'0' }}
```

Comment: Timezone comes from server and is encoded in ISO format. I don't know it in other way. Each date can have different timezone.

Comment: You can use the ISO timezone provided by the server in the date filter as well. I think the filter supported ISO timezones...